# React native: change button size in center screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new to React Native currently learning about the technology.
I start create a card layout with buttons inside it.

This is my layout :

```
   <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior='padding'
        keyboardVerticalOffset={50}
        style={styles.screen}>
        <LinearGradient
            colors={['#ffedff', '#ffe3ff']}
            style={styles.gradient}>
            <Card style={styles.card}>
                <ScrollView>

                    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                        <Button
                            color={Colors.primary}
                            title='ورود'
                            onPress={() => { }} />
                    </View>


                </ScrollView>
            </Card>
        </LinearGradient>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

and this is my stylesheet :

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        flex: 1
    },
    gradient: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    card: {
        width: '90%',
        height: '80%',
        padding: 20
    },
    buttonContainer: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginVertical: 30,

    },
});
```

and result is:

[image]

I want to make button bigger so i added **width** to **buttonContainer** but button changed position to left of screen and its size does not change.

```
buttonContainer: {
    width: '40%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginVertical: 30,

},
```

How could i change button **width** when it is in the center of screen?

Comment: can you share a working example in expo snack so that we can check and revert

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/HJowrvo0B @GauravRoy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem with :

```
buttonContainer: {
    width: '40%',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginVertical: 30,
}
```

Now this is my layout:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So basically alignSelf:'center' was the problem. Removing that worked. Check the expo link below and the code :

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    TextInput,
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    ScrollView,
    Button
} from 'react-native';


import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient'


import Card from './Card';



export default AuthScreen = () => {
    return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
            behavior='padding'
            keyboardVerticalOffset={50}
            style={styles.screen}>
            <LinearGradient
                colors={['#ffedff', '#ffe3ff']}
                style={styles.gradient}>
                <Card style={styles.card}>
                    <ScrollView>
                        {/* <View style={styles.wcContainer}>
                            <Text style={styles.headerText}>خوش آمدید</Text>
                        </View> */}

                        {/* <View style={styles.container}>
                            <Text style={styles.text}>نام کاربری</Text>
                            <TextInput style={styles.input} />
                            <Text style={styles.text}>رمز عبور</Text>
                            <TextInput style={styles.input} />
                        </View> */}
                        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                            <Button
                                color= 'red'
                                title='ورود'
                                style={{marginHorizontal:200}}
                                onPress={() => { }} />
                        </View>


                    </ScrollView>
                </Card>
            </LinearGradient>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        flex: 1
    },
    gradient: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    card: {
        width: '90%',
        height: '80%',
        padding: 20
    },
    buttonContainer: {
        // marginHorizontal:200,
        width:'100%',
        // alignItems: 'center',
        // marginVertical: 30,
        justifyContent:'center'

    },
});
```

expo link : [expo link](https://snack.expo.io/HJowrvo0B)

hope it helps. feel free for doubts